# Where can I find secondary NIC in nordlynx VPN?

Tags: wireguard

I remember that Nordlynx uses double NAT to fix the privacy issue of Wireguard by using 2 NICs per each client. But when I install nordlynx app and try to connect, there is only one interface called nordlynx.

After the connection is made successfully, ip address is assigned to it, but I just wonder where is the secondary interface and the assigned address is dynamic or static.

Hope your kind advice, thanks very much!

Comment: What privacy issue with WireGuard and how would two VPN interfaces solve it?

Comment: When we configuring wireguard conf files, there should be ip addresses of peers for sure, this can be a weakness to expose client's credential information to attackers

Comment: Regarding their solution, you can get it by reading this; https://nordvpn.com/blog/nordlynx-protocol-wireguard/#:~:text=What%20is%20NordLynx%20and%20how,it%20while%20it's%20in%20transit.

Comment: There’s nothing in this document about two VPN interfaces on the client. All the supposed privacy-enabling measures take place on the NordVPN servers.

Comment: No VPN interfaces, they say that there are 2 local network interfaces per each client, and basically this is double NAT system's architecture. First interface is used to assign same ip address to all users, and second one is to assign random addresses after connection is made

Comment: “this can be a weakness to expose client's credential information to attackers” - How do you figure? Those credentials are already being submitted through encrypted connections. A VPN doesn’t protect you from MITM attacks.

Comment: You know, wireguard only uses static IP addresses not dynamic one, in case of server is hacked, then all ip addresses can be taken by attackers. Using this information, he can trace each client's traffic. There are some other possibilities why this becomes privacy issue in nordvpn's official site, for example WebRTC attack.

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpret [the description](https://nordvpn.com/blog/nordlynx-protocol-wireguard/). The image is pretty clear on how things work:

> [image: NordLynx schema]

(Original size in the linked page.)

To work around the purported privacy problem<sup>1</sup>, every user’s WireGuard connections are terminated in a container (or VM, the circle with the key icon) that does authentication and has *two* virtual network interfaces: The VPN adapter (connected to the user) and a virtual Ethernet interface (connected to the larger NAT network). The VPN adapter has a *static* IP address. The virtual Ethernet interface has a *dynamic* IP address.

You, the user (circle with person icon), have only *one* virtual network interface: The VPN adapter (connected to NordVPN). The only address you see is *static*.

Note 1: The *privacy* problem is very constructed and the architecture described in the article does *not* make it impossible for NordVPN to log all connections, it just splits two concerns of the VPN routing process, making end-to-end logging a little harder. It is not about WebRTC or anything, only about logging, which NordVPN may or may not do.